# Google SMTP settings not sending email

Tags: smtp, gitlab

I am having a hard time making the email sending in GitLab to work (changing email in profile settings). My server has `exim4`, I can tell its working because if I do simple `mail()` in PHP, it thus sends the email to the recipient. Now, in GitLab seems that it wasn't. So I modified **productions.rb** to have SMTP settings, and use Google SMTP:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    user_name: "user@gmail.com",
    password: "hashpassword",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

I even tried changing the port to **587** and **467** but still it doesn't work. Why is that? Can you please lead me to where I am missing?

Comment: The default GitLab mailer uses sendmail. Rather than testing with PHP, try running sendmail from the terminal and verify that THAT works. IIRC PHP uses sendmail too, but to rule out any configuration weirdness I suggest going right to the source.

Comment: Also, did you make sure to restart the server after changing the port?

Comment: It is better to give some error log.